# Can I have different SSL certificates for different subdomains?

Tags: wordpress, https, dns, ssl-certificate

My company has a SSL certificate for *.mycompany.com. We use this certificate for many critical services.

Marketing team owns www.mycompany.com website (WordPress) and wants a SSL certificate for it.

Can we issue a specific certificate for www.mycompany.com?

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/351368/using-single-domain-ssl-and-wildcard-ssl-in-parallel-on-different-ip-addresses), yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. as far as the certificate is concerned there is no relationship between different servers. You could have five different servers with five different certificates and as long as each one of them is valid there wouldn't be a problem. (it *might* cause a problem if the certificate changes mid-session)

You should however be aware that www.example.com would also be usable as a certificate for any of your other 'critical' services that operate on www.example.com, you could have a security issue there.

Comment: Critical services look like foo.mycompany.com, bar.my company.com.

Comment: Do you mean we can have multiple *.mycompany.com certificates?

Comment: As long as the certificate covers the domain name you're connected to and is signed by a trusted authority (And not revoked) then that is the only check made, there it's no mechanism to know what other certificates are in existence